# Why is this returning bool(false)?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I have this query that checks if a movement exists and supposed to return true or false. This query

```
function movement_performed_today($class_id, $client_id){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;



$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `date` = CURDATE()");

$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$return = (mysql_result($movement_performed, 0) == 1) ? true : false;   
    var_dump ($return);
}
```

Returns:

```
bool(false) 
bool(false)
```

If I replace this code:

```
$return = result(mysql_result($movement_performed, 0) == 1) ? true : false; 
    var_dump ($return);
```

With this:

```
print_r ($movement_perfomed);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [COUNT(`movement`)] => 2 ) 
Array ( [COUNT(`movement`)] => 3 )
```

Am I completely wrong to think since these numbers are anything other than zero it should return true?

Comment: Why do people do things like `(condition) ? true : false`? Your `condition` is already a boolean, there's no point in doing that, other than to befuddle other people looking at your code. On a more serious note, don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: I edited the code as the result was not supposed to be in there. I am very new at this and this query is based off other querys I have done or been shown how to do.

Comment: Regarding PDO do I have to switch my db connection to PDO to begin using PDO queries?

Comment: @Colbyd Yes, when you create a new PDO object it establishes a new connection. Read the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: @NullUserException I was planning on switching all my mysql to PDO but thought I would need to start with my connect.php file and change it over to PDO before using any of my PDO queries.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc returns false when there are no returned rows in the result set. Also you are not checking with mysql_error right after mysql_query. You should also check with mysql_num_rows before using mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: @NullUserException I posted the new query that is working and `var_dump` now produces bool(false) or bool(true) depending on if the `movement` exists. I now am trying to call this function inside a while loop and if it returns `false` do this function otherwise keep on going. This is not working. Can you look at to see if I am performing this properly? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question:

`mysql_result` returns `FALSE` on error. You are passing the array from `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of the mysql resource as required by `mysql_result`'s function signature:

```
string mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row [, mixed $field = 0 ] )
```

Thus it returns `FALSE` because it has an error.

---

A better way:

```
// Change
$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$return = result(mysql_result($movement_performed, 0) == 1) ? true : false;

// to
$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_row($query);
return $movement_performed[0] > 0;
```

This grabs the result of the count statement and does a `> 0` check on it. The `> 0` check is not really needed but helps show intent rather than relying on on truthy values.

---

*Side note: the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated.  You should migrate your code to use `MySQLi` or `PDO`. You are unfortunately using the fact that many `mysql_*` functions do not need the `mysql` resource.  Migrating your code will be a pain because you have to change a bunch of functions or declare global variables.  I recommend the former option but it will take a lot of effort to fix.*

Comment: @LeviMorrison thanks for the help that worked. I posted the php loop above where Im calling this function and what Im trying to accomplish. Can you take a look and tell me what Im doing wrong when calling this functioin?

Comment: Now when I do a `var_dump ($return)` it get `bool(true) bool(true)` which is correct since `movement` does exist from this user in this class on this day. When I do `var_dump (isPerformed)` from the while loop it returns NULL and therefore executing the function which I dont want it do if returns true.

Comment: can you tell me what this line does `$return = $movement_performed[0] > 0;`

Comment: @Colbyd Did you actually say `return $return;` in your function? You have to return the result from the function.  I edited my code example to reflect this.

Comment: my code currently looks like this `$return = $movement_performed[0] > 0;`

Comment: @Colbyd Change it to `return $movement_performed[0] > 0;` and see if `isPerformed` is still `NULL`.

Comment: that worked. Thank you...you'll have to forgive my ignorance on this. Im pretty green incase you couldnt tell.

Comment: now it returns bool(false) not matter if `movement` exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be

```
(count(mysql_fetch_assoc ) >0 ) ? true : false;
```

rather than

```
result(mysql_result($movement_performed, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) (replacement for [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)) exists for a reason.